# How to pass value from one provider to another directly in flutter

Tags: flutter, provider, data-sharing

I have 2 provider, `general provider` and `blog provider`. `general provider` is called on `splash screen` and here I normally call API that fetch most common data like blog, category, tags, notification and is stored in `general provider`. How can I use the same data and populate other provider from the 'general provider' itself ? reason to do so is save number of calls made on the start of the app.

Comment: Perhaps a proxy to front the general and blog providers. It could update the blog provider when retrieving from general. This is based on intuition only. I have not tried this approach.